# Jenkins - jmeter performance plugin - Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' changed build result to FAILURE Finished: FAILURE

Tags: performance, jenkins, plugins, jmeter

I m trying to generate performance report through jenkins peformance plug-in, when ever i try to perform build now. i get the error

```
- Started by user Mukesh kumar
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Aug17- Jmeter test
[Aug17- Jmeter test] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\jenkins2034852437917248179.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Aug17- Jmeter test>C:\Users\ux010725\Downloads\Softwares\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\Users\ux010725\Downloads\Softwares\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\TestPlan_Aug14.jmx -l Mukesh_Reports\r2.xml 
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\ux010725\Downloads\Softwares\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\TestPlan_Aug14.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Aug 17 15:48:37 IST 2018 (1534501117309)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =     42 in 00:00:09 =    4.6/s Avg:   208 Min:   113 Max:  2358 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Aug 17 15:48:47 IST 2018 (1534501127021)
... end of run
Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy C:\Users\ux010725\Downloads\Softwares\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\Mukesh_Reports\r2.xml to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Aug17- Jmeter test\builds\17\temp\r2.xml
Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing spaces in « Aug17- jmeter test »

This might explain the failure